# What does sign a distribution point mean?

Tags: deployment, sccm, system-center, distribution

I am looking at some guides on Microsoft Configuration Manager Console, and see that you need to sign a distribution point on packages etc. Can someone explain this a bit further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For automated deployments you need a certificate pair; it's pretty easy to do since you'll also need PKI installed for native mode anyway.